# Facebook Object with ID '' does not exist - for public, existing pictures

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

For some odd reason I cannot get the picture data on API. Eg. for this picture https://www.facebook.com/10206158396036508

request:

```
curl -i -X GET \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/10206158396036508?access_token=(...)"
```

response:

> Unsupported get request. Object with ID '10206158396036508' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation.

Image is public and was found through facebook's search on pictures. I got the ID from the URL https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10206158396036508&set=basw.A(...)&theater

Doing the same (search -> videos -> get ID from the URL to the video -> check it on Graph Explorer) works for videos but it doesn't on pictures for some reason I can't figure out... most other posts talk about private pics, but those are clearly public, so I should be permitted to query them just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not matter if public or not, that picture is on a user profile and you can only get data of user profiles if that specific user authorized your App. In that case, the `user_photos` permission would be needed too.